# Elegant method for swapping unequal list slices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've looked into swapping elements in lists on this site but most cases deal with swapping one element with another.

Here I am trying to swap the position of slices of unequal length. For an example list:

```
x = [6,2,4,3,4,1,4,5]
```

I was hoping for an elegant way used to swap values in lists and variables in general such as the form below:

```
x[0:1], x[1:7] = x[1:7], x[0:1]

#Expected output
x = [2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Unsurprisingly it doesn't work, it swaps the first two elements:

```
#Actual output
x = [2, 6, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5]
```

Another example: Swap `x[0:4]` with `x[5:7]`:

```
#Expected output
x = [1, 4, 4, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

I hope it's clear that the swapping is such that the first element of the `slice1` occupies the previous location of the first element of `slice2`. The rest follows.

Is there a simple way to do this elegantly and efficiently?

Comment: The only "elegant" way I can see to support arbitrary sequence assignments involving slices is to define a custom object wrapping the list, whose `__set_item__` method would keep track of previous slice assignments and re-map the indices for the following ones.  Making this efficient --- e.g. O(logN) w.r.t. the number of assignments --- will require a non-trivial data structure for keeping track of index transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.deque` to rotate the values:

```
import collections
x = [6,2,4,3,4,1,4,5]
d = collections.deque(x)
d.rotate(-1)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: The question (in my reading) is about swapping arbitrary slices of different sizes.  Rotating is just one (easy) subcase.

Comment: But this wouldn't work for the second case, right? Where the last value position is maintained but the two elements before it are swapped with the first 3 elements. @nickie states it correctly

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to do this with just lists is with straight slice concatenation:

```
x = [6,2,4,3,4,1,4,5]
x = x[1:] + x[:1]  

print x
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

For the second case, you slice it up in three pieces similarly.

---

Analysis of posted failure:

Your attempted assignment is of the wrong form: multiple assignment is done expression to expression, not as a stream of values.  What you entered breaks down to a **parallel** evaluation and assignments of

```
x[0:1] = x[1:7]
x[1:7] = x[0:1]
```

If you do these individually, you'll see that the assignment is restricted to the smaller slice in each case.

Comment: This generates a new list.  The question (in my reading, again) is about in-place substitution.

Comment: This fails the second example

Comment: @Yukon: thanks.  I didn't notice the boundary problem.  Fixed and improved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any elegant, fully-general way. Here's a not-so-elegant way:

```
def swapslices(l, from1, to1, from2, to2):
    if not (from1 <= to1 <= from2 <= to2):
        raise ValueError('slices out of order or overlapping')
    if to1 - from1 == to2 - from2:
        # Easy case. No need to shift the part between the two slices.
        l[from1: to1], l[from2, to2] = l[from2: to2], l[from1: to1]
    else:
        # Hard case. We need to rewrite the whole section.
        l[from1: to2] = l[from2: to2] + l[to1: from2] + l[from1: to1]
```

This function requires that you pass the lower slice first, and that you don't try to use slices like `6:3`.

The function relies on the fact that if you try to swap slices `a` and `c` here:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    ----  ----  -------
      a     b       c
```

doing so is equivalent to replacing the whole `a + b + c` section with `c + b + a`:

```
[0, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 9]
    -------  ----  ----
        c      b     a
```

Example:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> swapslices(l, 1, 3, 5, 8)
>>> l
[0, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough:

```
def swapslices(lst, from1, to1, from2, to2):
    # assumes from1:to1 < from2:to2
    def reverse(l, r):
       r = r - 1
       while l < r:
           lst[l], lst[r] = lst[r], lst[l]
           l += 1
           r -= 1
    reverse(to1, from2)
    reverse(from2, to2)
    reverse(from1, to1)
    reverse(from1, to2)
```

try it with

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
swapslices(a, 2, 4, 6, 9)
# a is now [0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 10]
```